# Data migration tool: is it possible to exclude specific websites/stores (and all of their related settings, products, etc.) from the migration?

Tags: magento2, multistore, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have a Magento 1 website with a bunch of legacy websites (stores) which haven't been used for years but which still contain a bunch of old products/settings/etc.

I'm migrating to Magento 2 but don't want to migrate the old stores.

What's the best way to exclude these old stores and only migrate the store(s) I need?

Obviously I would want to exclude not only the store data itself but all of the product associations and store-specific settings related to the old stores.